# Probability of $k$ fixed points for a random function from and to $\{1,..,n\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-functions, derangements

I would like to derive the probability mass distribution $p_k$ of the number $k$ of fixed points of a random function from $A:=\{1,..,n\}$ to the same set.

1. I proceed computing the number of derangements $D_n$, as per a random permutation, obtaining:
   $$ D_n = n^n - \binom n1 n^{n-1} + \binom n2 n^{n-2} - .. (-1)^k\binom nk n^{n-k}=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom ni n^{n-i}.$$
2. Then I compute the number of random functions with $k$ fixed points $n_k$ as the product of $\binom nk$ and $D_{n-k}$, as if to say that each function is composed by a $k$-subset of $A$ times a deranged $n-k$-disposition of the remaining $n-k$ elements of $A$:
   $$n_k=\binom nk \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} (-1)^i\binom {n-k}i (n-k)^{n-k-i},$$
3. so that
   $$p_k = \frac{n_k}{n^n}=\binom nk \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} (-1)^i\binom {n-k}i \frac{(n-k)^{n-k-i}}{n^n}.$$

To me it makes sense, but a quick check on Python shows me that $\sum_{k=0}^n p_k\neq 1$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: But $\binom{n}{k}D_{n-k}$ implies that your function is onto, no?

Comment: Do you require your random function to be a bijection (i.e., a permutation)?

Comment: Note... while there are $D_n$ **permutations** (*which are necessarily bijective*) over $n$ elements with no fixed points, there are $(n-1)^n$ **functions** (*not necessarily bijective*) with no fixed points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179297/jmoravitz) pointed out in a comment, to find the number of functions with $\ k\ $ fixed points you need to multiply $\ {n\choose k}\ $ by the number of *functions* with no fixed points on $\ n-k\ $ elements—namely $\ (n-1)^{n-k}\ $—, *not* the number of derangements. Thus,
\begin{align}
p_k&=\frac{{n\choose k}(n-1)^{n-k}}{n^n}\\
&= {n\choose k} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) ^k\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-k}\ .
\end{align}
That is, the distribution of the number of fixed points is $\ Binomial\big(n, \frac{1}{n}\big)\ $.  Another way of seeing this is that each of the numbers $\ 1,2,\dots,n\ $ is independently and equally likely to be a fixed point with probability $\ \frac{1}{n}\ $.

Comment: right, thank you and to @JMoravitz